# How to change service account for GKE nodes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

My GKE cluster was created long back and it has two nodes currently both using the default Service account.
I want to now change the Service account for the nodes without disturbing the cluster.
I want to maintain a separate SA for our cluster. I looked for it, but it looks like a non-editable property.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: My piece of advice: Prefer [Workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#workload_identity) to node identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't modify the `service account` of a `node-pool` that was already created.

Below you can find a screenshot from `Cloud Console` that states the `service account` setting is permanent in the creation process:

[image: NODE POOL]

---

To avoid having downtime with your workload and create a new `node-pool` with different `service account` you can follow the official documentation about migration:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Tutorials: Migrating node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool)*

> This tutorial demonstrates how to migrate workloads running on a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster to a new set of nodes within the same cluster without incurring downtime for your application. Such a migration can be useful if you want to migrate your workloads to nodes with a different machine type.

You will need to:

- Create a new `node-pool` with your `service account`.
- Migrate the workload to the new `node-pool` (draining and cordoning old `node-pool`).
- **Check if everything is running correctly on a new `node-pool`**.
- Delete the old `node-pool`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Hardening your cluster: Use least privilege SA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#use_least_privilege_sa)*

Comment: This is a great answer, but what if we are using Autopilot? Is there a way to trigger recreating the nodes?

Comment: @SachinMeier it’d be a great question to ask directly on stack/server fault. Unfortunately I cannot answer this question now.